# Limit UIAppearance proxy scope

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I'm currently using the appearance proxy object for customising my application interface.

I would like to know if it's possible to limit the effect of the customisation to elements inside a specific view controller.

In other words, can I use

```
[UINavigatioBar appearance]
```

to change the colours and font attributes inside one specific screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the appearanceWhenContainedIn method to limit the scope of appearance proxy to view contained within a certain container class.  e.g.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], nil] setTintColor:myToolbarColor];
```